# Trying to figure out a query where age of a person is less than rest of people

Tags: mysql

My apologies. I have an interview tomorrow and totally freaking out.

Going thru some sql questions...

```
Table name :person 
ID int
Name char
Age int

print all the pairs of names where first person  age is less than second age (ordered by first person id)

Line contains two separated names (name of first and second person) order by first and then by second person id
```

Comment: Relax and ask a real question and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name
FROM person p1, person p2
WHERE p1.age < p2.age
ORDER BY p1.id, p2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE age =  ( SELECT MIN(age) FROM person )
```

Comment: This doesnt print the pair of names?

Comment: this only gives person with minimum age, whereas the question requires a set of users consisting of younger and older persons